# Polymer 1.0 paper-menu with recursive template

Tags: html, templates, menu, polymer

This must be a useful and widely applied design to stack menus dynamically and from a custom element. I spent hours debugging this and come so far as some events (iron-select) are not being propagated [correctly].

In short

```
<paper-menu>
  <mycustommenu data="menuJsonDefinition"></mycustommenu>
<paper-menu>
```

where `mycustommenu` renders `paper-item` or `paper-submenu` recursively,

so in the end it looks like

```
<PAPER-MENU>
  <mycustommenu>
     <PAPER-SUBMENU>
        <PAPER-ITEM class="menu-trigger">submenutrigger</PAPER-ITEM>
        <PAPER-MENU class="menu-content">
          <PAPER-ITEM>xx</PAPER-ITEM>
        </PAPER-MENU>
     </PAPER-SUBMENU>
  </mycustommenu>
</PAPER-MENU>
```

It WORKS so far. But as soon as we add recursion and replace inner

```
<PAPER-ITEM>xx</PAPER-ITEM>
```

with `<mycustommenu>` which renders to

```
<mycustommenu><PAPER-ITEM>xx</PAPER-ITEM></mycustommenu>
```

it doesn't click/select anymore

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-submenu.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
</head>

<body>
    <dom-module id="paper-treeitem">
        <template>
            <template is="dom-if" if="{{data.folder}}">
                <paper-submenu>
                    <paper-item class="menu-trigger">{{data.name}}</paper-item>
                    <paper-menu class="menu-content" multi>
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data.children}}">
                            <!-- WORKING -->
                            <!-- COMMENT THIS LINE -->

                            <paper-item>{{item.name}}</paper-item>

                            <!-- NOT WORKING -->
                            <!-- UNCOMMENT THIS LINE -->

                            <!-- <paper-treeitem data="{{item}}"></paper-treeitem> -->
                        </template>
                    </paper-menu>
                </paper-submenu>
            </template>
            <template is="dom-if" if="{{!data.folder}}">
                <paper-item>{{data.name}}</paper-item>
            </template>
        </template>

        <script>
            HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
                Polymer({
                    is: 'paper-treeitem',
                    properties: {
                        data: {
                            type: Object,
                            value: function() {
                                return {};
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    ready: function(){
                        console.log(this, this.data)
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>

    <paper-menu>
        <paper-treeitem id="tRootTreeItem"></paper-treeitem>
    </paper-menu>

    <script>
        (function() {
            window.z = document.querySelector("#tRootTreeItem");
            z.data = {
                name: "Root",
                folder: true,
                children: [{
                    name: "File 1"
                }]
            };
        })()
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I posted it at github as well https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu/issues/93